# org.jetel.exception.JetelRuntimeException: while inserting csv file record: mule esb

Tags: salesforce, mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I insert csv file record into salesforce account.
I can insert successfully data into salesfore but got following error

```
ERROR 2015-02-03 14:21:39,709 [WatchDog_0] org.jetel.graph.runtime.SingleThreadWatchDog: Component [CSV READER:DATA_READER0] finished with status ERROR.
 Parsing error: Unexpected end of file in record 1, field 1 ("test_c"), metadata "report__c"; value: '<Raw record data is not available, please turn on verbose mode.>'
ERROR 2015-02-03 14:21:39,710 [WatchDog_0] org.jetel.graph.runtime.SingleThreadWatchDog: Error details:
org.jetel.exception.JetelRuntimeException: Component [CSV READER:DATA_READER0] finished with status ERROR.
```

I used following flow..

```
File->DataMapper->salesforce

<flow name="flow1" doc:name="flow1">
        <file:inbound-endpoint path="path" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" connector-ref="File"/>
        <data-mapper:transform config-ref="CSV_To_List_report__c_" doc:name="CSV To List&lt;report__c&gt;"/>
        <sfdc:create-bulk config-ref="salesforce" type="report__c" doc:name="Salesforce">
            <sfdc:objects ref="#[payload]"/>
        </sfdc:create-bulk>
        <logger message="Final #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

csv file format

```
25,36,45,25.36,15.20
27,88,56.25,66.33,25
```

what is the solution??

**1 more question
After salesforce i want to use java component..How can I use thta?
If i use java component then it gives me following error**

```
1. Failed to find entry point for component, the following resolvers tried but failed: [
ReflectionEntryPointResolver: Could not find entry point on: "com.org.Status" with arguments: "{class java.lang.String}"
MethodHeaderPropertyEntryPointResolver: The required property "method" is not set on the event
AnnotatedEntryPointResolver: Component: com.org.Status@8f5673 doesn't have any annotated methods, skipping.
CallableEntryPointResolver: Object "com.org.Status@8f5673" does not implement required interface "interface org.mule.api.lifecycle.Callable"
```

Thanks

Comment: I solved entry point resolver error. I use java transformer. Now problem is my java transformer called two times.. Why my transformer called two timeS???

Answer (score 0):

I solved both questions. I used idempotent filter and my transformer called only once

```
 <idempotent-message-filter idExpression="#[payload.state]" doc:name="Idempotent Message"/>
```